# Theme "Ronneby" problem in Wordpress, don't let me edit anything

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, undefined, offset

I am using ronneby theme by themeforest. Thanks to that theme, I can't modify almost all contents on the website admin. (BTW all was working some days ago)
The front works OK. You can check it at www.probiocolageno.com but the backend gives me this errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/nutrafood/public_html/probiocolageno/wp-content/themes/ronneby/inc/cleanup.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/nutrafood/public_html/probiocolageno/wp-content/themes/ronneby/inc/cleanup.php on line 59
```

The code in those lines is (this are lines 51 to 60):

```
/**
 * Clean up output of stylesheet <link> tags
 */
function dfd_clean_style_tag($input)
{
    preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' type='text/css' media='(.*)' />!", $input, $matches);
    // Only display media if it's print
    $media = $matches[3][0] === 'print' ? ' media="print"' : '';
    return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $matches[2][0] . '"' . $media . '>' . "\n";
}
```

---

Any clue from where to start will be appreciated

Edit: That function (`dfd_clean_style_tag`) is also in the same file, lines before (line 34): `add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'dfd_clean_style_tag');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
remove_filter('style_loader_tag', 'dfd_clean_style_tag');
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'your_dfd_clean_style_tag');
function your_dfd_clean_style_tag($input) {
    preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' type='text/css' media='(.*)' />!", $input, $matches);
    // Only display media if it's print
    if ( ! empty( $matches[3][0] ) ) {
        $media = $matches[3][0] === 'print' ? ' media="print"' : '';
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $matches[2][0] . '"' . $media . '>' . "\n";
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Max, got this error now:

[15-Nov-2019 15:25:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'dfd_clean_style_tag' not found or invalid function name in /home/nutrafood/public_html/probiocolageno/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 290

Comment: Man, you need find all hooks (actions and filters) who use dfd_clean_style_tag and remove their in the theme. But don't forget add this hooks for new function.

Comment: Got it, I will do it now. It's easy because there are only a few. 
Thanks!

Comment: The main problem was that I was with an old version of the template. I updated and all was solved.

Thanks for the awesome help.